# How do I resolve [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '1' did not find a matching property?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

It's just a warning, but I *would* like to resolve it:

```
 Jul 23, 2014 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '1' did not find a matching property.
```

I'm not sure where this is actually set to `1`, or which property. I've seen a few other questions that have this same warning, but none of the answers apply - I'm using Tomcat 7, it does, in fact, have `tomcat-util` and `tomcat-jdbc` and `log4j.jar` on the classpath.

I'm running Tomcat 7 under Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon further diagnosis, digging through source, and lots of grep, I have discovered the issue is with `/etc/tomcat7/context.xml` (symlinked as `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/context.xml`)

This contained a `<Context debug="1" ...>` element. Which apparently doesn't make any sense to tomcat. I removed that, and I no longer get that warning.

Comment: Any user defined context in "$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/" directory can cause this problem and the solution is the same.